# Unexpected Output in JavaScript 2D Array Population

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array `ele`, and I want to populate another array `arr` with copies of `ele`, and then return the populated array.  The JavaScript function I have is:

```
function foo(n) {
    var arr = new Array(n);
    var ele = [0,1];

    for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        arr[i] = ele;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

for e.g. `foo(3)`, the output I want is `[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]`, but I instead get the output: `[#1=[0, 1], #1#, #1#]` (using Firefox's Web Console).  When I instead populate `arr` with [0,1] directly, as in

```
function fooNew(n) {
    var arr = new Array(n);

    for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        arr[i] = [0,1];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I get the correct output for `fooNew(3)`: `[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]`.  Why does my original function `foo` not give the same output as `fooNew`?  That is: why can't I populate `arr` by assigning `ele` to `arr[i]`, and instead have to populate it by assigning the content of `ele` directly to `arr[i]`, to get the output I want?

======

Update: in light of Felix Kling's helpful answer, and after some googling, I found that by using slice(0), you can place a copy of ele into arr[i] rather than a reference to it. So the following modification of foo will give the desired output:

```
function foo(n) {
    var arr = new Array(n);
    var ele = [0,1];

    for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        arr[i] = ele.slice(0);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Just as a comment, I see it correctly both on Firefox/Firebug and Chrome. Just be careful, on the first example, you're assigning a reference to the SAME `ele` array to all the positions on `arr`. So if you do something like `x = foo(3); x[0].push(2);`, now all the arrays on x have three elements (Because they're actually the same array)

Comment: Works for me. In Chrome, Firefox (Firebug) & Node.js. As @julio.olvr said be careful when assigning `ele`. Arrays, like objects `{}` are pointers to collections. So if `var x = [1,2,3]` and then `var y = x` and then `y[0] = 9` you will end up with an x of `[9,2,3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Firebug's output is quite helpful in this situation <sup>†</sup>. It tells you that every element of your resulting array references the same array:

```js
  [#1=[0, 1], #1#, #1#]
//  ^----------^----^
```

`#1` (or `#1#`) is a placeholder for the array `[0, 1]`, indicating a reference.

It is still an array of arrays, it's just differently represented by Firebug.

I'm not sure if this is what you want though. For example, if you modify the first element of the first array:

```
result[0][0] = 5;
```

the result would be

```
[[5,1], [5,1], [5,1]]
```

I assume you want the arrays to be independent from each other, therefore you have to assign a new array each time. This is what you do in the second case.

---

†: But it is also a reminder that one should not always believe everything one sees. The state of an object (for example) can be quite different from how tools represent it. [Here is an article about such a case](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/) (sorry for self promotion), the issue is fixed in Firebug, but not in Chrome (afaik).

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know what to make of the notation "#1#" (google won't let you query such strings, it seems), but this makes sense.

Comment: I don't normally use Firebug, but that output is really clever and useful. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @user1238742: You're welcome :) If it helped you, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick outline next to it.